# Computer Management not loading on windows server 2019 standard

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2019

I'm using Windows Server 2019 Standard Evaluation and computer management does not load.

All the icons load, but nothing else.

[image: Screenshot.]

How can I make computer management load properly? The Windows + X menu does not load either.

Comment: That is built right into Windows.  Try running DISM / SFC   .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John Thanks, This Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> computer management does not load, all the icons load, but nothing
> else

That function is built right into Windows.

DISM and SFC will often repair this:

1. Open `cmd.exe` with Run as Administrator.
2. `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup`
3. `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth`
4. `SFC /SCANNOW`
5. Restart when all the above is complete and test.

You have noted that this repairs the issue.